# OpenAI whisper medium WER does not decay for low resource language

Tags: openai-api, openai-whisper, whisper

Does anyone know why the WER does not decay? I'm fine tuning the openai whisper medium model for  low resource language?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bmPl.png)

`per_device_train_batch_size="32"`
`per_device_eval_batch_size="16"`
`learning_rate="1e-5"`

Comment: Here are some questions: How is your data prepared? What language are you fine-tuning on? How much data do you have?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

- How is your data prepared:
   The data is semi-normalized (removed all non my-language specific punctuations, brackets, ...), but I didn't remove the langue specific punctuations and keep casing because I need the output to have punctuations and special names with uppercase.

- What language are you fine-tuning on: 
   Armenian language

- How much data do you have? 
   53 hours data, consisting of less than 30sec long audio files and appropriate sentences (25k samples in total)

Comment: Unfortunately, 53 hours is not a lot of data, compared to the 680,000 hours Whisper was trained on. Can you do augmentation at all to increase the number of hours of data you have?

Comment: Have you also experimented with the learning rate? And can you use some sort of mechanism to change the learning rate if your loss in plateauing? That is, how are you fine-tuning Whisper?

Comment: @KathyReid I appreciate your help. I found the reason. I used scripts provided by openai community (whisper train event). The script has some issues. After fixing them I got better WER (even for 53 hours dataset). Now I'm working on a bigger dataset to decrease the WER.